# gnuplot plot timeseries minute resolution in the x-axis

Tags: gnuplot

I have a time series at second level.
I'm using

```
set timefmt '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'
set xdata time
```

My x-axis have time with second precision (09:45:00)

is it possible to show time only at minute precision (09:45..09h50..etc) instead of(09:45:00..09:50:00 etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set timefmt` sets the format which is used to read the data file. To set a different output format for the x-axis, use e.g.

```
set format x "%H:%M"
```

Then you must also set the xtics accordingly. To have a major tic every five minutes, use

```
set xtics 5*60
```